# Selenium c# loop through local variables

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I need to loop through some local variables which are used to drive a class that gets data from an excel sheet.

Basically I have 18 questions with radio button answers so I want to be able to loop through these and based on the value in the excel data select the right radio button. My thinking is I would loop through question 1 to 18 and then use a split to set the right radio button.

Here is my code

```
//Loops questions 1 through 18
int i = 0;
int ex = 1;

do
{
    var Answer = userData + (".Question" + ex);

    Console.WriteLine(Answer);
    switch (Answer)
    {
        case "Strongly Agree":
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_MainBody_Client_lvRiskProfileQuestions_ctrl" + i + "_radAnswerID_" + 4 + "']")).Click();
            break;
        case "Agree":
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_MainBody_Client_lvRiskProfileQuestions_ctrl" + i + "_radAnswerID_" + 3 + "']")).Click();
            break;
        case "Neither Agree nor Disagree":
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_MainBody_Client_lvRiskProfileQuestions_ctrl" + i + "_radAnswerID_" + 2 + "']")).Click();
            break;
        case "Disagree":
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_MainBody_Client_lvRiskProfileQuestions_ctrl" + i + "_radAnswerID_" + 1 + "']")).Click();
            break;
        case "Strongly Disagree":
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_MainBody_Client_lvRiskProfileQuestions_ctrl" + i + "_radAnswerID_" + 0 + "']")).Click();
            break;
    }

    i++;
    ex++;
} while (i < 18);
```

My problem appears to be that the Answer variable is not being set to the value in excel but rather the link its self. The output from the write line is `OnlineStore.TestDataAcess.ExcelTestDataParser.Question1`
and so on.

Any suggestions of how to get this working will be greatly received

Comment: What is the value of userData, can you give an example + show what sets the value of it?

Comment: userData is set as `var userData = ExcelDataAccess.GetTestData(testName);` where ExcelDataAccess is a class that contains the connection string and the query to interrogate excel

Comment: I don't know how your testing framework is implemented but it looks like your `ExcelDataAccess.GetTestData` method is returning a parser object rather than your test data: is there a method of the `ExcelTestDataParser` class that can give you the parsed data?

Comment: Yes that is how it works for other items. And does work if I manually use userData.Question1 for example. The problem comes when I try to use a variable to loop through 1 to 18 of the questions. I think the problem is I cant get the code to interpret this `var Answer = userData + (".Question" + ex);` like I had it hard coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try getting the fields of the ParserObject and then getting their value dynamically. For example:

```
var questionNumber = "Question" + i;

var field = userData.GetType().GetField(questionNumber);
var userResponse = field.GetValue(userData);
var Answer = userResponse + (".Question" + ex);
```

This should give you the value of whichever question you pass to GetField. Note that GetField returns null of the method is not found so you might want to wrap the `field.GetValue` in a try-catch.

Also this will only work for member variables not auto-implemented properties i.e. those defined like `public string Question1 {get; set;}`.

If the questions are added as auto-implemented properties, you can do this instead:

```
var questionNumber = "Question" + i;

var property= userData.GetType().GetProperty(questionNumber);
var userResponse = property.GetValue(userData);
var Answer = userResponse + (".Question" + ex);
```

This also assumes a lot about your Parser object, how is each question represented in the parser class?

Comment: I had to user the GetProperty option (Although they are not auto-implement properties as per your example) and then I had to convert the output to string to get my switch to work but after that this is perfect!

Comment: Glad I could help, sorry it took me so long to understand your issue! Not sure why you're having to manually convert it to a string though, I assumed that the type of your `QuestionX` members were strings though I suppose they could technically be anything.

Comment: No problem. Im new to c# and Selenium so probably not the best at explaining exactly what I need (The whole reason for trying what I did was because its how I would have done it in VBA.) On you other point it was retaining it as an object which the switch couldn't handle.